# How to configure CruiseControl.Net for Windows Authentication?

Tags: windows-sbs-2008, windows-authentication, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol

I am using CruiseControl.Net for continuous integration which is now accessing the dashboard through login plugin, which in turn is authenticating and authorizing after verifying it with a set of users saved as XML file in the CruiseControl.Net server.

Now, i need to bring in Windows Authentication to the system whereby which CruiseControl.Net server webdashboard when accessed from a client machine(local machine associated with a common server), would be authenticated and be authorized to access the CruiseControl.Net features based on the authority of the logged in users.

Kindly guide me to go ahead with this, appreciate all kinds of resources that would be helpful for achieving this.

Thanks.

Comment: I am facing the same issue more than a year later. I think the support for Windows authentication is not implemented at all. IIS puts the identity in `HttpContext.User` and this is never used in the source of ccnet. I found instead only the use of `Cookies["CCNetSessionToken"]`... Not sure how to add the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that there is a big obstacle: the security is implemented in the ccnet server, not in the webdashboard. That makes it quite difficult to integrate with windows authentication mode. Removing it from the ccnet server is not a good idea as the ccnet-tray tool accesses directly the server using .NET remoting and needs authentication... For me it sounds like there is no way to solve this without a big architectural change.